# Facing problem to construct x path for below code

Tags: selenium

```
<div id="param-selection-div" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    
                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown dynamic-dropdown cached-dropdown open" id="select-product-dropdown" title="Select">
                    <div>Product</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-box" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Select" value="Select">Select<span class="custom-caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu custom-dropdown-border" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="select-product"><li title="CRM"><a href="#">CRM</a></li><li title="OMS"><a href="#">OMS</a></li></ul></div>
    
                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown dynamic-dropdown cached-dropdown" id="select-version-dropdown" title="Select">
                    <div>Release</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-box" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Select" value="Select">Select<span class="custom-caret"></span></button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown dynamic-dropdown cached-dropdown" id="select-phase-dropdown" title="Select">
                    <div>Phase</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-box" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Select" value="Select">Select<span class="custom-caret"></span></button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown dynamic-dropdown cached-dropdown" id="select-group-dropdown" title="Select">
                    <div>Group</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-box" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Select" value="Select">Select<span class="custom-caret"></span></button>
                </div>
    
                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown dynamic-dropdown cached-dropdown wide-dropdown" id="select-env-dropdown" title="Select">
                    <div>Environment</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-box" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Select" value="Select">Select<span class="custom-caret"></span></button>
                </div>
                
                <div id="submit-selections">
                    <button class="btn custom-submit-btn" id="submit-selections-button" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" onclick="getEnvOperations();cacheDropDownSelections()" disabled="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Get Environment Details">
                        FILTER
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn no-borders-btn" id="" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" onclick="clearDropDownsCookieEntry();initDropDowns()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Clear Selection">CLEAR
                    </button>
                </div>
                    
            </div>
```

Comment: <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown dynamic-dropdown cached-dropdown open" id="select-product-dropdown" title="Select">
     <div>Product</div>
     <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-box" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Select" value="Select">Select<span class="custom-caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu custom-dropdown-border" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="select-product"><li title="CRM"><a href="#">CRM</a></li><li title="OMS"><a href="#">OMS</a></li></ul></div>

Comment: Which element do you want to select? Also please add more context and what code you have tried and what failure are you getting?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.